# Add incremental data attr value based on class name

Tags: jquery

I have some `<li>`s with class names as follows;

```
<li class="2014" data-order=""></li>
<li class="2014" data-order=""></li>
<li class="2013" data-order=""></li>
<li class="2013" data-order=""></li>
<li class="2013" data-order=""></li>
<li class="2012" data-order=""></li>
```

I need a jQuery function to add values to each an every `<li>` element's data-order. Value has to be set as follows.

```
<li class="2014" data-order="1"></li>
<li class="2014" data-order="2"></li>
<li class="2013" data-order="1"></li>
<li class="2013" data-order="2"></li>
<li class="2013" data-order="3"></li>
<li class="2012" data-order="1"></li>
<li class="2011" data-order="1"></li>
```

data-order will start from one. When multiple `<li>` having the same class, the data-order will start incrementing by 1.

Comment: AFAIK :) you cannot have *number* for classname it's like walking the highway, you can do it but...

Comment: I just used numbers for clear demonstration. It can be anything, I mean numbers+string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yogig/1/edit)**

```
var $ord = $('[data-order]');

$ord.each(function(){
  var $ordSib = $('.'+ this.className );
  return $(this).data('order', $ordSib.index(this)+1 );
});
```

Using `.index( this )` method from a jQuery elements Array collection will return the index position of that element. For index is '0' based you just need to increment than by `1`

Comment: Thank you very much Roko. Not only got the answer but also got an idea about the difference between this and $this.

Comment: @Body yes, `this` is the JS reference, while `$(this)` is just jQuery passing the JS's `this` to it's Object.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayOfClasses=[];

$('li').each(function(){
    var elementsClass=$(this).attr('class');
    if($.inArray(elementsClass,arrayOfClasses)==-1){
        arrayOfClasses.push(elementsClass);
    }
});

for(var i in arrayOfClasses){
    var className=arrayOfClasses[i];
    var count=0;
    $('li').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass(className)){
            count=count+1;
            $(this).attr('data-order',count);
        }
    });
}
```

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/hezeteqa/1/watch?html,css,js,output)